# RegisterPage.js:30 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to get user information by using redux but the request fails with error 500 and the network response returns this kind of error message "{"err": "E11000 duplicate key error collection: private.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "samarkan@mail.com" }"}".I'am very confused friends,please can someone help me to fix it there's all  my code:

```
userReducer.js:
import Axios from "axios";


export const register = ({name, fname, phone, email, password}) => async (dispatch)=> {
    dispatch({type: "USER_REGISTER_REQUEST", payload: {name, fname, phone, email}});
    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.post("api/users/register",{name, fname, phone, email})

        dispatch({type: "USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS", payload: data })
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({type: "USER_REGISTER_FAIL", payload: error.response && error.response.data.message ? error.response.data.message : error.message})
    }
};

export const registerReducer = (state = {loading: true, userinfo: {}}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "USER_REGISTER_REQUEST":
        return {loading: true}
        case "USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS":
            return {loading: false, userInfo: action.payload};
            case "USER_REGISTER_FAIL":
                return {loading: false, error: action.payload}
        default:
            return state;
  }
};
```

`````
registerPage:
import React from "react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux";
import InputGroup from "./common/InputGroup";
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import {register} from "../reducers/userReducer";
import {useNavigate, useParams} from "react-router-dom";

const RegisterPage = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
   
   const [name, setName] = useState('');
   const [fname, setFname] = useState('');
   const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
   const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState('');
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const validateEmail = (email) => {
    return String(email)
      .toLowerCase()
      .match(
        /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
      );
  };


  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    if(password === confirm && validateEmail(email)) { 
     
        dispatch(register({name, fname, phone, email})).then((user)=> navigate({pathname: "/profile", search: `?id=${user._id}&name=${user.name}&fname=${user.fname}&email=${user.email}`}) );
    
      
   
    } else {
        window.alert("password and confirm password not the same try again or email not conform!")
    }
  }

  
  
    return (
        <div>
        <h2>Welcome to private <span>Let's be private</span></h2>
       
        <p id="icon" >Pr</p>
        <div className="form">
            <InputGroup value={name} type="text" label="name" name="name" onChange={(e)=> setName(e.target.value)}  />
            <InputGroup value={fname} type="text" label="fname" name="fname" onChange={(e)=> setFname(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={phone} type="phone" label="phone" name="phone" onChange={(e)=> setPhone(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={email} type="email" label="email" name="email" onChange={(e)=> setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <InputGroup value={password} type="password" label="password" name="password"  onChange={(e)=> setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            <InputGroup value={confirm} type="password" label="confirm password" name="confirm"  onChange={(e)=> setConfirm(e.target.value)} />
            <button onClick={(e)=>submitHandler()} >Register</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
};
export default RegisterPage;
````


````
store.js:
import { createStore } from "redux";
import {compose, applyMiddleware} from "redux";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {registerReducer} from "./reducers/userReducer";


const initialState = {user: {}};



const reducer = combineReducers({
    
user: registerReducer
    

});

const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore( reducer,  initialState, composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
export default store;
````


[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3kBH.png
`````

Comment: Looks like that error tells you everything. You are trying to register user with that specific email and it looks like the email is used as a primary key. However, a row with that email already exists hence it throws you an error ```duplicate key error collection: private.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: "samarkan@mail.com" }```. Check your database

Comment: yes my friend that's true i waked up to this error, change all the inputs includes email the action  become  success but without rendered data also it give different name state "cart"

Comment: This `dispatch(register({name, fname, phone, email})).then((user)` will not work since your thunk is not returning a value. You  need to either return a value from the thunk or get `userInfo` from the state via `useSelector`.